# Cannot set attribute of a subclass

Tags: python

I am trying to add an attribute to a subclass (self.resource_map). However, its value is always {NoneType} None, even after initializing an instance of the class.

```
class Resource(collections.Counter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resource_map = {
            'O': 'Ore',
            'W': 'Wood',
        }

    def set_to_zero(self):
        super(Resource, self).__init__([(k, 0) for k in self.resource_map.keys()])
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your result. For me, `x = Resource(); print(x.resource_map)` outputs the dictionary.

Comment: Well, in fact __init__() is required to return None. But If your intention is to set all the keys to 0, you can try something like: self.resource_map = [(k, 0) for k in self.resource_map.keys()] in set_to_zero function. Here: https://onlinegdb.com/S1SimMXbI

Comment: Somehow it prints it, but if I inspect it I get: Unable to display children:Error resolving variables Traceback (most recent call last). 
Perhaps because the class is a dictionary and I am storing a dict within a dict?